# Getting XML entire element, from search results

Tags: xml, perl, search, grep

I have a bunch of XML files, each with the format ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
    <R>
        <B></B>
        <Q></Q>
        <U></U>
    </R>
    ...
</A>
```

I need to search for strings in each, and return the entire element "R". The problem is there are new lines with the strings, so I cannot use grep -B n -A n because the number of lines before and after may be different for each search result

For example, given the following ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
    <R>
        <B>abc</B>
        <Q>0123</Q>
        <U>xyz</U>
    </R>
    <R>
        <B>
            qwe
            rty
            yui
        </B>
        <Q>0123</Q>
        <U>
            zxc
            abc
        </U>
    </R>
    <R>
        <B>lkj</B>
        <Q>
            lkjhgfdsa
            wer
        </Q>
        <U>
            poixyz
            zaq
        </U>
    </R>
</A>
```

If I grep for "xyz", then I need to get ...

```
<R>
    <B>abc</B>
    <Q>0123</Q>
    <U>xyz</U>
</R>
<R>
    <B>lkj</B>
    <Q>
        lkjhgfdsa
        wer
    </Q>
    <U>
        poixyz
        zaq
    </U>
</R>
```

I'm not opposed to using other tools like perl, egrep, etc... to accomplish this. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn [XPath](http://enwp.org/XPath) and use [xml_grep2](http://p3rl.org/xml_grep2).

```
$ xml_grep2 -x '//*[text()[contains(string(.),"xyz")]]/ancestor::R' nvanwyen.xml

<R>
        <B>abc</B>
        <Q>0123</Q>
        <U>xyz</U>
    </R>
<R>
        <B>lkj</B>
        <Q>
            lkjhgfdsa
            wer
        </Q>
        <U>
            poixyz
            zaq
        </U>
    </R>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done in Perl, e.g. with the `xpath` executable that comes with [XML::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-XPath-1.13/):

```
xpath a.xml '//R[.//*[contains(text(),"xyz")]]'
```

or with an alternative, such as mine (this site won't let me link to it), which is based on [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0016/):

```
xpath-rp -e '//R[.//*[contains(text(),"xyz")]]' a.xml
```

Another option is [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//R[.//*[contains(text(),"xyz")]]' a.xml
```

P.S.: These are just alternatives to daxim's answer.
I wasn't aware of xml_grep2 and I will install it right away!
The main point is that it's a good idea to use XPath here.

Comment: I can't get either of these solutions working. Neither seems to produce any results ... must be me.